# How to copy last row of data in all worksheets and paste it into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a lot of sheets in my Excel file but I want to get the last row of data in sheets that start with "6" as their names as the other sheets are not relevant. In the sheets that start with 6 are all in the same format but have different number of rows, I am interested in extracting the last row in all those sheets (columns D:J) and placing it into a "master sheet". Since I am quite new to VBA, how would I go about doing that? Thanks in advance!

What I have currently that can copy one sheet and paste into my master sheet "Sheet2":

```
   With Sheets("6363")
        With Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp), _
                   .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1").Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will copy the last row, columns D-J, from every sheet with a name that starts with '6'.

It will put the copied data into the next empty row, starting at column D, of 'Sheet2'.

```vb
Sub CopySix()
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim rngDst As Range

    Set wsDst = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set rngDst = wsDst.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    For Each wsSrc In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Left(wsSrc.Name, 1) = "6" Then
            Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(, 7)
            rngDst.Resize(, 7).Value = rngSrc.Value
            Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next wsSrc
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response, for some reason it is not producing any results. Do I need to make changes if my data starts at D6?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, it copies the last row of data. There was a slight typo in the code I posted though but I've fixed that.